# Proving that an improper integral is continuous provided that the integrand is continuous and that the integral is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis

On a previous discussion found in [Continuity of improper integral with a continuous integrand.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581766/continuity-of-improper-integral-with-a-continuous-integrand) Matematleta explains how to prove an improper integral is continuous given the fact that the integrand is continuous and that the integral is uniformly convergent. But I do not understand some details of his proof. I'll provide what I understand so far.

Let $$F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(s,t) dt$$

So I believe by the triangle equality and the linearity of the integral we have

$$\left | F(s)-F(z) \right | \leq  \left | \int_{0}^{M} f(s,t)-f(z,t) dt \right | + \left | \int_{M}^{\infty} f(s,t)-f(z,t) dt \right |$$ $(1)$

Now since we know that $f(s,t)$ is continuous, that means that $\left | f(s,t)-f(z,t) \right | < \epsilon$ whenever $d((s,t),(z,t)) < \delta_{1}$, where $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta_{1} > 0$. I have not really seen the notation of $d((s,t),(z,t))$ before, but from my research, I'm assuming it means a metric of distance, but is that right?

Continuing with the proof, we find that by the triangle equality we have

$$\left | \int_{0}^{M} f(s,t)-f(z,t) dt \right |\leq \int_{0}^{M} \left | f(s,t)-f(z,t) \right | dt \leq  M\epsilon$$

I believe that this also comes from the triangle equality and the linearity of the integral, but we also have $$\left | \int_{M}^{\infty} f(s,t)-f(z,t) dt \right |\leq  \left | \int_{M}^{\infty}f(s,t)dt \right | + \left | \int_{M}^{\infty} f(z,t) dt \right |$$

Since we know that $F(s)$ is uniformly convergent, one can choose M such that $$\left | \int_{M}^{\infty}f(s,t)dt \right | < \epsilon$$ $(2)$
$$\left | \int_{M}^{\infty}f(z,t)dt \right | < \epsilon$$ $(3)$

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ together we have $$\left | \int_{M}^{\infty} f(s,t)-f(z,t) dt \right |  < \epsilon$$ $(4)$

Here is what I do not understand. If we were to combine $(1)$ and $(4)$, from my understanding we should have 
$$\left | F(s)-F(z) \right | \leq (M+1)\epsilon$$
But isn't it supposed to be less than or equal to $\epsilon$ to complete the proof? Also, I'm pretty sure that $\delta$ is defined as $$\left | s-z \right |<\delta$$ so according to the link I provided, why is $\delta = \delta_{1}/2$? The three questions I have listed are the things that I do not understand about this proof of how F(s) is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you can make your estimate of $\left|\int_0^\infty (f(s,t) - f(z,t))\; dt\right|$  arbitrarily small.  If you want it less than $\epsilon$, change the $\epsilon$ in the previous part of the proof to $\epsilon' = \epsilon/(M+1)$.  Then you'll get $$ \left|\int_0^\infty (f(s,t)-f(z,t))\; dt\right| < (M+1) \epsilon' = \epsilon$$
Similarly, you can use $\delta_1$ instead of $\delta$ if needed for the proof.

EDIT: BTW, from (2) and (3) you actually get
$$ \left| \int_M^\infty (f(s,t) - f(z,t))\; dt \right| < 2 \epsilon $$
not just $\epsilon$.  So use $M+2$ instead of $M+1$.

I don't see where Matematleta  actually used $\delta = \delta_1/2$.  You actually need the fact that continuous functions on a compact set are uniformly continuous, so that there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - z| < \delta$ implies 
$|f(x,y) - f(z,y)| < \epsilon'$ for all $y \in [0,M]$.

Comment: I get the first part now, but how do you use $\delta_{1}$ to finish the proof? Also, how is $\delta = \delta_{1}/2$?

Comment: That helps so much, thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: Why is it supposed to be less than 2$\epsilon$ by the way? Is it because when we subtract we add up the results? Or did I do something wrong in my proof earlier?

Comment: It's the triangle inequality.  If $A = \int_M^\infty f(s,t)\; dt$ and $B = \int_M^\infty f(z,t)\; dt$, then $\left| \int_M^\infty (f(s,t)-f(z,t))\; dt\right| = |A - B| \le |A| + |B|$.

Comment: True I almost forgot that.